# Unable to add a condition to a while loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, conditional-statements

I have a `while` loop which looks like this:

```
while ((min_t_border>0) && (colided_border_num > 0) && (~(min_t>0)))
    ...
end
```

I want to add to it another condition: `(exit_border_point ~= false)` or `(exit_border_point)`
when I put ether of the conditions above in an `if` statement it works. But when I try to add it as an additional condition to the while, or even when I try to add another condition to the if, for example I've tried `if ((exit_border_point ~= false) && (true))` it tells me:

"Operands to the `||` and `&&` operators must be convertible to logical scalar values."

What am I doing wrong?

*`exit_border_point` gets ether a `(3x1)` vector or `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `exit_border_point` can be a vector, try using the `any` or `all` functions, like this:

```
if (~any(exit_border_point))
```

As you can probably guess, `any` returns `true` if anything in the array evaluates to `true` and `all` returns `true` if everything in the array is `true`. They're kind of like vector equivalents to `||` and `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

For the condition to make sense in the context of an `if` or `while` statement, it should evaluate to a scalar.

Thus, you should write

`all(exit_border_point)`

(which is equivalent to `all(exit_border_point == true)`), if you want `true` if all are true. Replace `all` with `any` if you want to exit the while-loop as soon as any `exit_border_point` is true.

Note that `&&` and `||` only work for scalars. They're short-cut operators in that the second statement won't be evaluated if the first one determines the outcome (e.g. evaluates to `false` in case of `&&`. If you want to element-wise compare arrays, use `&` and `|`.

Answer (score 1):

If `exit_border_point` is a 3x1 vector then `(exit_border_point ~= false)` also returns a 3x1 vector, hence the error. Use this condition instead:

```
~isequal(exit_border_point, false)
```